# Failed to load cakephp css/base.css files

Tags: php, css, apache, cakephp

Having troubles in loading css files...I have newly installed cakeapp (my project name) in root folder i.e home/teja/var/www/html$ and my root folder has permissions of 777... I downloaded cakephp 3.1.1.1 using globally installed composer while installing it asked me for the permissions as to set default i selected yes.......... and then I when to cakeapp folder in terminal i run bin/cake server it showed succes. I when I tried loading at  http://localhost/cakeapp/  it popped up these errors:

[image]

Comment: Probably your unshown apache config is a) not pointing at the webroot dir and b) does not have allow-override-all/mod rewrite. Debug with that in mind, also see [the notes about url rewriting in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply I will check it @AD7six